# Как сложить List BigDecimal и добавить результат в одну строку

Tags: java

Сюда добавляю элементы `List<BigDecimal> sumSecond = new ArrayList<>();`
Здесь вызываем работника `employeeList.get(i)`, у которого возвращаем заработную плату `getSalary()`, а тут прибавляем её к `sumSecond`, а затем необходимо сохранить это число в наш лист.

Проблема в том, что прибавлять BigDecimal к BigDecimal нужно через `.add()`, добавлять элементы в List тоже нужно через `.add` . В связи с чем вот эта строка не работает полностью
`sumSecond.add(sumSecond.add(employeeList.get(i).getSalary()));` Как мне ещё производить это действие, если хочу в одну строку.

Comment: вы ничего не прибавляете, sumSecond.add(sumSecond.add - вы дважды вызываете метод добавления в коллекцию , потому как sumSecond - это ваша коллекция List<BigDecimal> sumSecond, а не переменная типа BigDecimal, а поскольку метод add  для листов возвращает boolean, то второй раз вы пытаетесь добавить boolean в коллекцию типизированную BigDecimal, на что и ругается компилятор

Comment: Да, разобрался, спасибо. Я понимал, что не добавляю, просто мне нужен был вариант как решить эту проблему, в конечном итоге просто другую переменную завёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлять все равно придется руками так как результат работы List.add это boolean.

**Но есть выход по типу такого**

BigDecimalList.java

```
package test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BigDecimalList extends ArrayList<BigDecimal> {

  public BigDecimalList addItem(BigDecimal item) {
    this.add(item);
    return this;
  }
}
```

App.java

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Optional;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Optional<BigDecimal> sum =
      new BigDecimalList()
        .addItem(BigDecimal.valueOf(1321654.21))
        .addItem(BigDecimal.valueOf(334.21))
        .addItem(BigDecimal.valueOf(12134.21))
        .addItem(BigDecimal.valueOf(5656.21))
        .stream().reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b));

   System.out.println(sum.isPresent() ? sum.get().doubleValue() : 0);
  }
}
```